# Which kind of bug cause the iOS 4 alarm failed?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, logic

As you know this [alarm bug](http://news.cnet.com/8301-13579_3-20026911-37.html),

"We're aware of an issue related to nonrepeating alarms set for January 1 or 2. Customers can set recurring alarms for those dates and all alarms will work properly beginning January 3."

Read more: http://news.cnet.com/8301-13579_3-20026911-37.html#ixzz19temSRs9

I just wonder why it is just related to 2011/1/1 and 2011/1/2 but not other day?

Comment: We're not Apple, how would we know?

Comment: Someone at Apple wanted to have the weekend off.

Comment: Have a look at different ISO week-number codings, they are kind of complex and I suspect the problem to lie there. I.e. saturday was week 1 of 2011 but also week 53(?) of 2010. Otherwise I don't see what could have gone wrong. (this especially since it seems related to weekdays, as you say for monday there is no problem anymore)

Comment: This is not a bug, it's a feature. You're *supposed* to sleep in on the first day of the new year.

Comment: How is this not a valid question?  How is it off topic? Isn't this a programming site?  The person is asking if there is some sort of weird anomaly associated with the two dates apple said it wouldn't work on.

Comment: This question is "off topic" because some programmers are lazy and/or lack of imagination. sigh.

Comment: Apple never show its source code to us. I know we don't have a chance to know the root cause of this issues. So my question must now have answer.