# How did the iPhone Alarm Bug possibly happen?

Tags: iphone, calendar, timezone

iPhone alarms didn't work in the new year of 2011! http://www.engadget.com/2010/12/31/psa-iphone-alarms-not-working-come-new-years-day-2011/

But only on January 1st. And January 2nd. And only if there were single-event alarms. (Recurring alarms still sounded.)

How did this possibly happen? What contortions of code lead to this outcome? What absurd algorithms give rise to this inscrutable behavior? Is it related to November's daylight saving time related alarm foul-up?

I don't know, and odds are, the only people who do aren't talking.

For this question, don't be silent just because you're not positive. Guesses encouraged. Tales of similar mistakes strongly encourage. **Extra points for pseudocode.**

Comment: prizes for guesses how many times this non-question will occur in the next week?

Comment: Closed. While this (interesting) question is linked with *algorithms*, it is more a discussion than an actual question. Maybe it would fit another SE site?

Comment: I thought it was an amazing question, and I don’t understand why anyone would vote to close it. It isn’t ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical, and it certainly can be answered in its current form. I’m likely to be up much of the night trying to think of an answer.

Comment: I also thought this question was a good idea [when I first read it on Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/33225/apple-new-year-alarm-bug-cause)—7 hours before this one.

Comment: It is an actual question. I'm asking for ways to reasonably implement an alarm clock that operates this way. How is that a non-question?

Comment: May also refer here for possible insight(s): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579360/which-kind-of-bug-cause-the-ios-4-alarm-failed

Comment: @joshpaul - and also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582134/iphone-4-alarm-stopped-working-in-2011).

Comment: Please reopen, this is a valid question